# How to test large services with Junit?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I'm new to testing with junit. We have two service methods with so many db calls like selects and inserts on multiple tables. Basically the application is a Spring MVC application with Some REST endpoints.

I would like to test my service layer methods. Each service method invokes DAO methods. The DAO layer is wrapped up with JPA entity manager. The service methods do not return any thing, the return type is void for both the methods. How could i test the methods with Junit?

Is Junit itself sufficient for this or do i need any other things like Mockito?

Please suggest. I have searched in google, but didn't get them working. Little confused to move forward.

Comment: It sounds like these large, complex service methods are excellent candidates for refactoring. I would most likely break up these methods into a set of smaller, functionally cohesive methods, and then test them all independently. The big monolithic method may remain, but will delegate to a number of other components. And, yes, JUnit and a mocking framework (e.g. mockito) is definitely able to test this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please provide me a good reference link for this?

Comment: Martin Fowler is the go to author for [refactoring](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r95004/Refactoring_improving_the_design_of_existing_code.pdf), and here is a good reference on [using Mockito with JUnit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_junit_integration.htm)

Comment: In an EJB-Environment we use ejb-cdi-unit. Spring has something similar, in earlier days there was SpringUnit. The idea behind that is, to start a smaller test-container in the Test-Setup, mock external calls, perhaps use H2 or another in memory db to mock the database.
The testing framework helps in creation of TestPersistenceUnits, simulating Transactional calls and simulating  messagequeue, ....

I call that module-tests. The advantage I see in working this way, is, that in my experience extensive mocking hinders refactoring at a later time, because of the lack of information hiding.